# VS 2015 Tools for Cordova - DOM Manipulation

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, content-security-policy

I am migrating a deployed Cordova 3 app to Cordova 5 under VS 2015 (previously used a Mac for Cordova) and I am encountering a DOM injection problem.  When I configure my project for Android my project works fine with the Android emulators, however when configured for Windows Phone I start getting DOM manipulation exceptions deep inside jQuery.

Is there not something within CSP (Content Security Policy) that controls this behavior ?   There does not appear to be, I have configured CSP to allow anything and everything for now.   The message I get is as follows:

*0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.*

I am obviously interested in having a common code base for all platforms.

Help !.....what am I missing here ?

Comment: I can use the toStaticHTML method to resolve the problem, however given that the Cordova objective is to develop for multiple platforms I do NOT want to use a Microsoft specific only method.   I do not want any Microsoft specific JavaScript code in my Cordova apps.

Comment: An example of the DOM manipulation that I need to do is to populate a drop-down with selection values that are only known at runtime.